# MySQL Tables / Schema are duplicating themselves

Tags: mysql, sql, schema, mysql-workbench, workbench

All of a suddned I noticed that my tables have began to duplicate themselves and I don't know why or what I have done to cause this. Does anyone know?  The last thing I remember doing is setting up Indexes for Full Text Searches.   Any help is appreciated.

Here is an example of what my tables are looking like:

[image]

The duplicated tables have no Columns or Indexes, but the original table does. Why would this suddenly occur?

[image]

All the duplication is listed under Schema and is only occuring for about 50% of the tables in the Database.

[image]

[image]

Comment: you have a code that runs this creates

Comment: not that I know of?

Comment: how can i check that?

Comment: the text are not randpm. sp you make a table afdsalknv-amelia-events, if you have programming see there, it could be also a install process, a stored procedure, you pbasically have3 to check everything, read the manual of the software you are trying to use

Comment: In which area is this table list? It's certainly not the schema tree in the SQL editor, which shows objects from a server. Is this in modeling, forward engineering perhaps?

Comment: i believe it's the schema tree. i'll post another picture for you

Comment: OK, did you try to refresh the list (click the small button in the upper right corner)? Have you checked with another tool (e.g. MySQL Shell) to see if there are really duplicate objects? The thing is that names cannot appear twice, so it might just be a display issue in Workbench.

Comment: I just tested with PHPMYADMIN and it's the same.  So, I don't think the issue is Workbench. I'll attach a screenshot

Comment: OK, that's really odd. I guess you should set up your schema again. Something got broken there.

Comment: Bugger. I thought so.  Thanks for your support Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved by restarting the server!